# how to fix this number sorting python code so that it works correctly

Tags: python, join

This is regarding a number sorting program. I am not able to understand the syntax with the `join` line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
ar=[]
for arg in sys.argv:
    ar.append(arg)  
ar.sort()
print " ".join('%s'%x for x in ar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the `join` line looks super funky.

`" ".join(...)` will take a list (or any iterable) of arguments and create for you one string where all the arguments arguments are separated by one space.

In this case I would just pass in your sorted list `ar`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
ar=[]
for arg in sys.argv:
    ar.append(arg)

ar.sort()
print " ".join(ar)
```

Now we have two more problems:

- The first argument on the command line will be the name of your script. I'd use `sys.argv[1:]` instead of just `sys.argv`.
- You're sorting the strings that are passed in, and not the numbers. this will lead to a sort like `[1, 11, 13, 2, 3, 4, 5, 56, 9]`. To remedy this, I'd use `ar.append(int(arg))`.

Comment: Using `ar.append(int(arg))` will mean that `" ".join(ar)` won't work though. You could avoid the permanent conversion by leaving `ar` as `str`, and doing the sort as `ar.sort(key=int)` so it sorts on `int` values, while preserving the original `str`.

Answer (score 1):

`'%s' % x for x in ar` is what is called a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression).  It generates a bunch of `'%s' % x` where `x` is defined as each item in `ar`.`" ".join(...)` puts a space between each item given to `.join()`.  When the generator is given, it puts a space between each item the generator generates.  If `ar` is not a list of strings, the generator converts each item to a string.  Then, we use  `" ".join(...)` to put a space between each of those strings.  `sys.argv` is always a list of strings, so you don't need that generator expression.  You could instead use `" ".join(sys.argv)`.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/5827958), it would be more efficient to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) anyway.  You would also use `str(x)` instead of `"%s"%x` just because it's easier to read.

Comment: Of course, since all the `x`s are `str`, you could skip the `str` conversion as well as the generator expression entirely and just use `ar` directly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Oops!  I missed that.  I've edited now.